# Selenium Chrome does not return Facebook user's post like in normal Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So recently I am trying to scrape Facebook's page/user's without logging in(I know login could solve so many issues but it also leads to a potential account ban). However, I have found that the page source returned does not match how it looks in a normal Chrome browser.

For example, for Facebook Page, you can see its post like this in normal Chrome (Not logged in, Incognito Mode)
[image]

For Facebook User, you can see its post like this in normal Chrome (Not logged in, Incognito Mode)
[image]

However, in Selenium, I am unable to retrieve the post content(actually what I only need is the newest post id).

The code is here for reference

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36")

chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36"})
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/<Page or User>")
print(driver.page_source)
```

I have tried adding/removing user-agent settings but seems no luck. The user-agent in the code is my current browser's one

What I want to do is to retrieve the post content(or only post id) in selenium chrome driver like it does in normal chrome. Thank you.

Comment: _I am unable to retrieve the post content_: What does `driver.page_source` prints?

Comment: Surprisingly, they probably have ways of blocking unauthorized usage such as yours.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So I wouldn't be surprised if they do things to make it harder for you to scrape them.

Comment: douuno if pastebin is allowed or not but this is the result(I'm using Heroku tho but I think I will get the same result locally) https://pastebin.com/AC2d4bUr . The post id I want to get is "472315224254546" but it does not exist in the page source. If you use a normal browser to watch this https://www.facebook.com/officiallexiunderwood you can see the posts are loading properly, but in selenium it does not work